# Is this Rails validation thread-safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, sidekiq, activemodel

This is running in multiple Sidekiq instances and workers at the same time and it seems that is has generated a couple of issues, like instances getting assigned the "It was alerted recently" error when shouldn't and the opposite.

It is rare, but it is happening, is this the problem or maybe it is something else?

```
class BrokenModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with BrokenValidator

end

class BrokenValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate record
    @record = record

    check_alerted
  end

  private

  def check_alerted
    if AtomicGlobalAlerted.new(@record).valid?
      @record.errors[:base] << "It was alerted recently"
    end

    p "check_alerted: #{@record.errors[:base]}"
  end
end

class AtomicGlobalAlerted
  include Redis::Objects
  attr_accessor :id

  def initialize id
    @id = id
    @fredis = nil

    Sidekiq.redis do |redis|
        @fredis = FreshRedis.new(redis, freshness: 7.days, granularity: 4.hours)
    end
  end

  def valid?
    @fredis.smembers.includes?(@id)
  end
end
```

Comment: @MikePerham so so you think this might be related with some resource sharing within the AtomicGlobalAlerted? I thought it might be some rails ActiveModel issue on sharing (at)record in different threads.

Comment: What is this AtomicGlobalAlerted thing?

Comment: It gets from Redis if something was already added to database. So this issue is happening minutes even hours after the id was already added, so it is not concurrency on persistency problem.

Comment: Why are you using `SMEMBERS` when a much more efficient (and actually atomic) `SISMEMBER` exists?

Comment: Also, you include redis objects, but you don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were experiencing something similar at work and after A LOT of digging finally figured out what was happening.

The class method `validates_with` uses one instance of the validator (`BrokenValidator`) to validate all instances of the class you're trying to validate (`BrokenModel`). Normally this is fine but you are assigning a variable (`@record`) and accessing that variable in another method (`check_alerted`) so other threads are assigning `@record` while other threads are still trying to `check_alerted`.

There are two ways you can fix this:

1) Pass `record` to `check_alerted`:

```
class BrokenValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)    
    check_alerted(record)
  end

  private

  def check_alerted(record)
    if AtomicGlobalAlerted.new(record).valid?
      record.errors[:base] << "It was alerted recently"
    end

    p "check_alerted: #{record.errors[:base]}"
  end
end
```

2) Use the instance version of `validates_with` which makes a new validator instance for each model instance you want to validate:

```
class BrokenModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :instance_validators

  def instance_validators
    validates_with BrokenValidator
  end

end
```

Either solution should work and solve the concurrency problem. Let me know if you experience any other issues.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there are some thread safety issues in rails but we can overcome them by taking necessary precautions.

The local variables, such as your local var, are local to each particular invocation of the method block. If two threads are calling this block at the same time, then each call will get its own local context variable and those won't overlap unless there are shared resources involved:  instance variables like `(@global_var)`, static variables `(@@static_var)`, globals `($global_var)` can cause concurrency problems.

You are using instance variable, just instantiate it every time you are coming to the `validate_record` method and hopefully your problem will go away like :

```
def validate record
    @record.errors[:base] = []
    @record = record
    check_alerted
end
```

For more details you can visit this detailed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184338/how-to-know-what-is-not-thread-safe-in-ruby)

Or try to study about rails configs here : [link](https://bearmetal.eu/theden/how-do-i-know-whether-my-rails-app-is-thread-safe-or-not/)

Comment: The quotation block: is it really a quote? If yes, provide a link to the source. If not, remove confusing markup.

Comment: I don't see why instantiating and then assigning would reduce any problem that is happening.

Comment: It will create new instance for each context and reduce the risk of concurrent processing

Comment: @sergio why this is confusing if its wrong then kindly provide a more correct description.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli: if it is not a quotation, it should not be marked as such.

Comment: @sergio Yeah its not a quote but it can be if its not wrong, i have removed quote but its not a reason to downvote the answer.

Comment: Downvote is because this answer is wrong. :) The proposed "fix" is meaningless. Does nothing to prevent the problem (are you sure you know what the problem is here?)

Comment: @sergio I have tried this solution in practical recently i was getting same values in some cases so i changed my instance var to local in that case problem was solved, so i proposed this same as mine resolved.