# Having a decrement (-=) function stop at 0 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following line of code which very simply decrements a Shareholders number of stocks (integer in the DB) when they sell them to someone else. This works well and as expected.

```
@selling_shareholder.update_attribute(:number_of_stocks, @selling_shareholder.number_of_stocks -= @transaction.number_of_stocks)
```

Very simply what I'd like to do is have the decrement function stop when the `number_of_stocks` hits 0 i.e. having a negative number should not be possible.

I guess I could use a simple `unless @selling_shareholder.number_of_stocks > 0` at the end of the line, but I'm wondering if that will actually work without using a loop?

Comment: Riddle me this. How can one have a `transaction` with a `number_of_stocks` in excess of their `number_of_stocks`? This seems like a simple validation `validates :number_of_stocks, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}` or if transaction is linked to the share holder than validate the number of stocks in the transaction prior

Comment: You are correct, I do not allow shareholders to sell more stocks than they own - and that is controlled in the view already, but what I was looking for here for some more assurance/safety on the back end - which now I've added via your model validation suggestion - thanks! :)

Comment: On a side note, try to avoid using operators like `+=` or `-=` because they aren't [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184752/1522214)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a method in your model called something like `#decrement_stock` that would handle that logic. You can set all kind of behaviors that should be expected, like raising exceptions. That approach follows the "[tell don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)" principle. It is also a simple unit of work performing a single task, making it easy to test with your favorite unit testing framework.

As engineersmnky suggested, simply adding validation on the model is also a good solution if you want the controller to handle errors.

Comment: Will go with the validation and logic in the model solution - thanks!

Comment: Much better answer. So much so that I'm deleting mine!